# What would be the best size for a full-width website slider image?

Tags: image, performance, optimization

I have a client who needs a slider to be full-width, without any containers or wrappers. I think it's bad practice(you may correct me otherwise), but I couldn't convince her otherwise. I'm concerned about the image sizes. The images are lazy-loaded, but still. One image can take a long time to download if I set it to be too large.

airbnb does it quite well here: https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/50724?s=jMlD

What should the maximum width of the images be?

Comment: So, Airbnb does it quite well... what exactly are your concerns? You have to convince me as well, not just your client. Image sizes obviously aren't much of a concern if there's one giant site "doing it well", and given todays proliferation of fast internet access.

Comment: @deceze I mean what should the image size be? Should I keep the images 1920, 2k, 4k, 5k? Fast internet access isn't available *everywhere*. I obviously want it to **look the best** while also working the best, you know what I mean? I said airbnb does it quite well, but, does it do it best, or is there a better way? The image would get blurry on a 5k iMac (I'm only stating the worst case scenario).

Comment: The best solution would be to resize your images dynamically (or pre-size them if they're not going to change) and choose the best fitting size via Javascript depending on the display size or perhaps guesstimated connection speed. E.g. `example.com/img/foo.2k.jpg`. You're supposedly using Javascript for the slider anyway, so this shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: @deceze That's perfect, though I have one last question; I'm using JS and it's lazy loaded through providing a data attribute. Got any alternatives to using media queries to use your above suggested solution?

Comment: Use `srcset` (https://responsiveimages.org/). This also what airbnb is using.